# How to put JSON object into an array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

```js
function initialize(woeid) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "php/getMapping.php",
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(overallArray) {

      console.log(overallArray);
      console.log(overallArray.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < overallArray.length; i++) {
        if (overallArray[i].woeid == woeid) {
          var cityArray = overallArray[i];
          break;
        }
      }
      var cityHashTags = cityArray.hashTags.split(";");


      document.getElementById("cityTitle").innerHTML = cityArray.name;
      document.getElementById("rssLink").href = "php/getRssFeed.php?woeid=" + cityArray.woeid;
      document.getElementById("cityDescription").innerHTML = cityArray.desc;
      document.getElementById("cityPopulation").innerHTML = `Population: ${cityArray.curPop}`;
      document.getElementById("cityCountry").innerHTML = `Country: ${cityArray.country}`;
      document.getElementById("cityLat").innerHTML = `Lat : ${cityArray.lat}`;
      document.getElementById("cityLong").innerHTML = `Long : ${cityArray.lng}`;

      for (var j = 0; j < cityHashTags.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("cityTwitter").innerHTML += "<a href='https://twitter.com/search?q=" + cityHashTags[j] + "' target='_blank'>#" + cityHashTags[j] + "</a>&nbsp&nbsp";
      }

      if (0 < cityArray.images.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cityArray.images.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById("cityPhotos").innerHTML += '<div class="w3-display-container mySlides w3-animate-opacity"><img src="pictures/poi/' + cityArray.images[i].imageFle + '" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><h4>' + cityArray.images[i].name + '</h4><p style="text-align:center;">' + cityArray.images[i].desc + '</p></div>';
        }
      }

      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('mapCanvas');
      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(cityArray.lat, cityArray.lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        disableDefaultUI: 1
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
      setMarkers(map, cityArray.poi);
    }
  });
}
```

[image]

I have attached the code of my Javascript. The array "overallArray" contains a JSON object. I attached a picture of the array. How can I put this whole data into 2 array? Two array should be based on the two woeid. Rest of the data goes under those two. I can hardcode the data but I am looking for a way to dynamically assign the key and value. I hope it all make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "on the 2 woeid"? Do you mean the two higher woeid or just two random ones?

Comment: if you look at the pictures, you can see a key {woeid: 44418, ..... This should be first element of the array. This element should have nested array it such as images.

Comment: when I run the same code in localhost apace server, the length of overallArray comes through as an 2 array. But when I run it from my domain account then the length of overallArray comes through as 14322. I do not understand why

Comment: Each word of those values acting as index. for Example console.log(overallArray[0]); is printing only - [                    console.log(overallArray[1]; is printing - {

Answer (score 0):

This will work something like , push Json array in existing Empty / jsonArray

```js
cityArray [];

let valuesX = {

  mapTypeId: document.getElementsByName('mapTypeId')[i].value,

  cityArray.push(valuesX);

}

var cityArray = JSON.stringify(cityArray);
```